# How to build and authenticate a token?

Tags: android, security, jwt, token

I have an android application with login button and reset the password with (MySQL) database on the server.
the app designed for both public people and for the clients of the app.

I need to add some advantage (using token) for my app but I don't know the scenario of using tokens how to create them and how to know is that a valid token for that client or not?

can you help me please with that problem?

Comment: `how to know`? Just save the token for each user on server and match it in each request . Token must be Unique .

Comment: okay , thank you for your answer.
after the user log out , that means the token is expire ?

Comment: It all depends upon how you want to handle the session of user . Its too complicated to answer here cause it will be advise only . Just read about Autherization in HTTP request and figure out a way to handle session as per your APP.